# in sqlite, how to update a column to null conditionally

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

In Sqlite, how can I update a varchar column to null if the value has length 0, otherwise to the value.

In other words, something like this, using C-like syntax:

```
update T set C = (value.length() == 0 ? null : value) where ...;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that the table schema has been defined to allow null values in the column then the following query should produce the results that you are looking for

```
UPDATE T
SET ColumnNameX = null
WHERE LENGTH(ColumnNameX) = 0
```

This could be enforced using a Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TNullTrigger
AFTER INSERT ON T 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE T
  SET ColumnNameX = null
  WHERE LENGTH(ColumnNameX) = 0
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a trigger, which I need to learn more about.  I'm curious why you have a where clause on the update.  Also, why are you ding the trigger "after" the insert rather than "before" - wouldn't that cause two updates to the table?

Comment: [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) actually has 3 types of triggers. AFTER INSERTallows you access to the replacement data. It means that you can better control the data going in and out, rather than just new data.

Comment: I've been experimenting with different trigger clauses to try to better understand the semantics.  I'm getting an error at runtime which I have posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414109/sqlite-trigger-causes-no-such-column-exception.  Feel free to have a look.