# sqlite trigger causes "no such column" exception

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm a newbie with sql triggers and am getting an ESQLiteException on what seems like a simple example.  When I try to modify the "memberTag" column in an existing row, I get the exception "no such column: memberTag".  If I drop the trigger, the exception goes away and the row gets updated.

I'm using SQLite and I'm using the "SQLite Expert Personal" app to do this experimenting.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [znode] (
  [description] CHAR NOT NULL, 
  [memberTag] CHAR);
```

and this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [memberTagTrigger]
AFTER UPDATE
ON [znode]
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN length(memberTag)=0
BEGIN
update znode
  set memberTag = null;
END;
```

My update experiment data is something like this:

```
description  memberTag
one          x
two          (null)
```

And when I try to change (null) to "y" using SQLite Expert Personal, it throws the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the WHEN clause: the database does not know where `memberTag` comes from, because there are *two* possible rows, the old one, and the new one.

Use either `OLD.memberTag` or `NEW.memberTag`.

(There is another problem: the UPDATE will change *all* rows in the table, because you forgot the WHERE clause.)

Comment: I tried that earlier on but get a syntax error when I prefix with "old.".  Maybe it's a bug in the GUI editor I'm using.  I'll try the command line (but will have a learning curve to figure that out).  Also, I was wondering about the where clause.  Can you recommend a source for a good semantic explanation of triggers?  So far all I've found are superficial overviews and a piecemeal assortment of examples.

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) explain how the pieces work. It is your job as a programmer to assemble the pieces so that they make sense. Think of `OLD` and `NEW` as two virtual tables, containing one row each.

Comment: That's pretty sketchy for "a good semantic explanation of triggers".  It's useful if you already know triggers well.  I'm looking for something more like a text book.

Comment: I'd agree with CL's answer. As for editors I suggest SQLite Manager for Firefox, Linqpad or spatialite-gui when working with Spatial data.

Comment: Ok, I've tried adding the trigger through the command line interface.  It gives me a syntax "Error: near line 1: near ".": syntax error" error when I prefix with "old.".  If I remove "old.", the trigger compiles but I get an error during update "Error: near line 1: near "memberTagTrigger": syntax error
Error: near line 2: no such column: memberTag".

Comment: Works for me, if I just replace `memberTag` with `new.memberTag` in the WHEN clause.